# Please suggest how to change join condition. Need to replace OR condition in JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This OR join is taking time. I need to avoid this join Please suggest.

```
 Select * from [A] a
 LEFT JOIN [B] b
 ON A.ID = b.ID OR a.ID = b.ID_REF
```

Comment: How do you expect an answer with this information? We don't know your database, how can we know what join condition you should use?

Comment: If `OR` is *correct*, I'm not sure what you expect us to do - especially if you think the fix is to change the query - rather than e.g. examining the query plan and identifying missing indexes, etc.

Comment: SQL SERVER database. I cannot able to share table details

Comment: You can replace the `OR` by `ON A.ID IN (b.ID, b.ID_REF)`, but this is just the same thing written differently; it won't change the execution plan. As mentioned, if the result you get with `OR` is correct, then your query is already as fast as it gets.

Comment: See http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/72730/44324

Comment: You can't share table details, but still ask for help... Then the general solution is indexes!

Answer (score 2):

Your query can be re-written with a `UNION`. You'd get the results for the first condition, then the results for the second, then merge the two.

```
SELECT * FROM [A] a LEFT JOIN [B] b ON a.ID = b.ID
UNION
SELECT * FROM [A] a LEFT JOIN [B] b ON a.ID = b.ID_REF;
```

This, however, is likely to be *slower* than your original query, because of the task to eliminate duplicates.

In case there can be no duplicates (i.e. `b.ID` never equals `b.ID_REF`) or you just don't care if you get some, then you can use `UNION ALL` instead. This simply glues both results without removing duplicates, so this may actually be faster than your query. You should have indexes on `A(ID)`, `B(ID)`, and `B(ID_REF)`.

```
SELECT * FROM [A] a LEFT JOIN [B] b ON a.ID = b.ID
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM [A] a LEFT JOIN [B] b ON a.ID = b.ID_REF;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without having any information about your tables, indexes, etc., this is naturally going to be an incomplete answer.  Having warned you about that, I would say that you could conceivably split this into two separate `JOIN` conditions and then alter your `WHERE` clause to reflect the importance/relevance of the `ID` fields, something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TableA A
LEFT JOIN TableB B1
    ON A.ID = B1.ID
LEFT JOIN TableB B2
    ON A.ID = B2.ID_REF
WHERE COALESCE(B1.ID,B2.ID_REF) = A.ID
;
```

This, of course, has the downside of potentially returning duplicate rows, and may even work more slowly than your original query, depending on your indexes/keys - but as stated, we're going to have a hard time giving a good answer with so little information about the schema you're working with.

Just using some super-simple dummy data to show you how this works:

```
DECLARE @TABLEA TABLE
    (
        ID INT
    );
DECLARE @TABLEB TABLE
    (
         ID INT
        ,ID_REF INT
    );

INSERT INTO @TABLEA
SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
SELECT 2
    UNION ALL
SELECT 3
    UNION ALL
SELECT 4
    UNION ALL
SELECT 5
    UNION ALL
SELECT 6
;

INSERT INTO @TABLEB (ID, ID_REF)
SELECT 1,NULL
    UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,2
    UNION ALL
SELECT 3,3
    UNION ALL
SELECT 4,NULL
    UNION ALL
SELECT NULL,5
    UNION ALL
SELECT 6,NULL
;

SELECT 
     A.ID AS [A_ID]
    ,COALESCE(B1.ID,B2.ID_Ref) AS [B_Final_ID]
FROM @TABLEA A
LEFT JOIN @TABLEB B1
    ON A.ID = B1.ID
LEFT JOIN @TABLEB B2
    ON A.ID = B2.ID_REF
WHERE COALESCE(B1.ID,B2.ID_REF) = A.ID
;
```

Returns:

```
A_ID | B_Final_ID
-----+-----------
 1   |  1
 2   |  2
 3   |  3
 4   |  4
 5   |  5
 6   |  6
```

I would seriously recommend that you consider supplying some dummy data, which would give nothing away about your actual database other than the structure of the tables.  That's the only way you're going to be able to get a better answer, in my opinion.